# Foreign Key makes Problems in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, foreign-keys

I would like to program an inventory system and need 3 tables for it. These can also be generated via artisan without a foreign key. But as soon as I want to add a foreign key, I get the following error message.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `inventar`.`#sql-fd4_141` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

(SQL: alter table `items` add constraint `items_lend_foreign` foreign key (`lend`) references `lending` (`id`))

Here my Code:

Item Table

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('barcode');
        $table->primary('barcode');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('room')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->string('annotation')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->integer('lend')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('manufactor')->nullable();



        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('items',function ($table){
        $table->foreign('lend')->references('id')->on('lending');

    });
```

Lending Table

```
Schema::create('lending', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();


        $table->integer('personid')->unsigned();

        $table->dateTime('startdate');
        $table->dateTime('enddate');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('lending',function ($table){
        $table->foreign('barcode')->references('barcode')->on('items');
        $table->foreign('personid')->references('personid')->on('persons');

    });
```

Persons-Table

```
 Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('personid')->unsignd()->primary();

        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('annotation')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I've also googled, but found no solution that works for me.

Is it a problem that my primary key is a string?

Comment: Try removing `nullable` from `lend`, it might be because laravel can't create nullable foreign keys, I think this happened to me too, if you want to use nullable, you can just remove the foreign key constraint

Comment: are you sure the migrations run the correct order. meaning does the `lending` table exist when the fk is being built?

Comment: I've already tried nullable removal. Unfortunately without success. I have now removed all foreign keys and everything works. I will now try step by step to insert the foreign key. I have already tried to generate only the table and then the foreign key. There were also problems.

Comment: Did you try moving this line $table->primary('barcode'); after Schema::table('items',function ($table){

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes in the line

`Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('personid')->unsignd()->primary(); 
}`

Change it to **unsigned()** from *unsignd()* and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem. It tries to create a table named "Inventar". This is the name of my database. I never create such a table. My code is on Github. Maybe I'm still missing something. Unfortunately, sleeping one night did not help. https://github.com/TheSlowlySnail/MT_Backend_Iventorysystem